# codeigniter form_validation from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i would like to access the following variable

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

From my controller. I tried

```
$this->form_validation->validation_errors();
```

With no luck. Not sure if this is even possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `validation_errors()` is a helper function, you can use it as it is in controller. i.e. in your controller:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

You'll need to load the helper first, of course.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::validation_errors() when trying to use it as is in my controller

Comment: Don't use it as `$this->form_validation->validation_errors();`...Just do `$this->load->helper('form');` and then `validation_errors();`